# Discord.js ban/kick commands available to all users. How can I fix this?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm making my own Discord Bot because I don't trust the bigger ones (Dyno, Hime, NosoBot, etc.) And my bot is pretty much done. The only problem is that my code allows all members to use these commands. I only want people to be able to use the functions they have permissions to. The code works, but how can I make it allow only people with permission to kick/ban?

```js
if (msg.content.startsWith("$kick ")) {
    if (msg.mentions.members.first()) {
        msg.mentions.members.first.kick().then((member) => {
            msg.channel.send(":wave: " + member.displayName + " has been successfully kicked :point_right: ");
        }).catch(() => {
            msg.channel.send("I do not have permissions to do this");
        });
    }
}else if (msg.content.startsWith("$ban ")) {
   if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return;
    if (msg.mentions.members.first()) {
        msg.mentions.members.first.ban().then((member) => {
            msg.channel.send(":wave: " + member.displayName + " has been successfully banned :point_right: ");
        }).catch(() => {
            msg.channel.send("I do not have permissions to do this");
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "KICK_MEMBERS" permission tells you if they have the permission to kick members, hence the name.

The "BAN_MEMBERS" permission tells you if they have the permission to ban members, hence the name.

Your Kick Command:

```js
if (msg.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) {
    if (msg.members.mentions.first()) {
        try {
            msg.members.mentions.first().kick();
        } catch {
            msg.reply("I do not have permissions to kick " + msg.members.mentions.first());
        }
    } else {
        msg.reply("You do not have permissions to kick " + msg.members.mentions.first());
    }
}
```

Your Ban Command:

```js
if (msg.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) {
    if (msg.members.mentions.first()) {
        try {
            msg.members.mentions.first().ban();
        } catch {
            msg.reply("I do not have permissions to ban" + msg.members.mentions.first());
        }
    } else {
        msg.reply("You do not have permissions to ban" + msg.members.mentions.first());
    }
}
```

The reason for the `try` and `catch` ensures that if the bot does not have permissions to kick or ban that user, it will not cause an error.

Another note:

You do not have to create another `bot.on('message')` event. Instead just use an `elseif`

Comment: This answer is from a couple years ago... however I'm noticing now that my msg object doesn't have a "members" property... what's the new way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Make a role in the server, and check for the role in your code

For example

```
if(!message.member.roles.find("name", "Admin"))
   return;
```

Would exit the method if the user does not have the role

So the code would look something like this

```
 if (message.content.startsWith("$kick")) {

    if (!message.member.roles.find("name", "Admin"))
        return;
    // Easy way to get member object though mentions.
    var member = message.mentions.members.first();
    // Kick
    member.kick().then((member) => {
        // Successmessage
        message.channel.send(":wave: " + member.displayName + " has been successfully kicked :point_right: ");
    }).catch(() => {
        // Failmessage
        message.channel.send("Access Denied");
    });
}
});
client.on("message", (message) => {
    if (message.content.startsWith("$ban")) {

        if (!message.member.roles.find("name", "Admin"))
            return;

        // Easy way to get member object though mentions.
        var member = message.mentions.members.first();
        // ban
        member.ban().then((member) => {
            // Successmessage
            message.channel.send(":wave: " + member.displayName + " has been successfully banned https://gfycat.com/playfulfittingcaribou :point_right: ");
        }).catch(() => {
            // Failmessage
            message.channel.send("Access Denied");
        });
    }
});
```

A nicer approach would be making a function that returns whether the user has the permission or not and using it in your code

Comment: I keep seeing that answer, where would I put that?

Comment: Thank you so much, Im making two bots and both had this problem!

Answer (score 2):

if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}kick`)) {

```
    let member = message.mentions.members.first();
    member.kick().then((member) => {
        message.channel.send(`:wave: ${member.displayName} has been kicked`);
    }).catch(() => {
        if (!message.member.hasPermission(['KICK_MEMBERS', 'ADMINISTRATOR'])) {
            message.reply("You cannot kick members");
        } else if (member.hasPermission(['KICK_MEMBERS', 'BAN_MEMBERS', 'ADMINISTRATOR'])) {
            message.reply("You cannont kick this member");
        }
    })
}
if (message.content.startsWith(`${prefix}ban`)) {

    let member = message.mentions.members.first();
    member.ban().then((member) => {
        message.channel.send(`:wave: ${member.displayName} has been kicked`);
    }).catch(() => {
        if (!message.member.hasPermission(['BAN_MEMBERS', 'ADMINISTRATOR'])) {
            message.reply("You cannot ban members");
        } else if (member.hasPermission(['KICK_MEMBERS', 'BAN_MEMBERS', 'ADMINISTRATOR'])) {
            message.reply("You cannont ban this member");
        }
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this for the roles permission:

```
if(message.member.roles.find(r => r.name === 'name of role')){
            //Enter command coding here
            }else{
            return message.channel.send('Enter Speech here')
            }
            break;
```

Maybe this might help you, i don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Hey i have something better for you

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');

if (message.content.startsWith(${prefix}BAN)) => {
    if (!message.guild.member(message.author).hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) { return message.channel.send('You do not have the permission for ban users"  !'); }

if (!message.guild.member(client.user).hasPermission('BAN_MEMBERS')) { return message.channel.send('I don\'t have the permission for ban users" !'); }

if (message.mentions.users.size === 0) { return message.channel.send('You need to ping a user !'); }
let banMember = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first());
if (!banMember) { return message.channel.send('User not found!'); }

        banMember.ban().then((member) => {
            message.channel.send(member.displayName + " has left the server")
            message.channel.send(member.displayName + " has been successfully banned by " + message.author);
        })
    }
```

Just delete BAN and replace by KICK

Answer (score 0):

```
    if (message.content.startWith(`${prefix}ban`)){
let buser = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0]));
if (!buser) return message.channel.send("Please provid a user to ban")
let reason = args.join(" ").slice(22)
if (!reason) return message.channel.send("Please provide a reason")
if(!message.member.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send("You don't have acces to this command")
if (buser.hasPermission("BAN_MEMBERS")) return message.channel.send("This user has the perm ban user")
let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
buser.ban()
.setAuthor("Ban")
.setDescription(`The user ${buser} has been ban for: ${reason}\n by the admin ${message.author.tag}`)
bot.channels.get("an channel id").send(embed);
```

}

Comment: In addition to the answer you've provided, please consider providing a brief explanation of why and how this fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (msg.content.startsWith("$kick ")) {
if (msg.author.hasPermission(`BANNING_MEMBERS`) {
    if (msg.mentions.members.first()) {
        msg.mentions.members.first.kick().then((member) => {
            msg.channel.send(":wave: " + member.displayName + " has been successfully kicked :point_right: ");
        }).catch(() => {
            msg.channel.send("I do not have permissions to do this");
        });
    }
}else if (msg.content.startsWith("$ban ")) {
   if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return;
    if (msg.mentions.members.first()) {
        msg.mentions.members.first.ban().then((member) => {
            msg.channel.send(":wave: " + member.displayName + " has been successfully banned :point_right: ");
        }).catch(() => {
            msg.channel.send("I do not have permissions to do this");
        });
    }
    } else {
msg.reply(`you can't ban members ask owner for admin`)
};

}
```

i recommend you to using prettierc (if you are coding in vs code eg. insiders)